# How to stretch parent div to fit children div?

Tags: html, css

How to stretch parent div to fit children div?

I tried to add element with `clear: both;` after content but it didn't work for me.

HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="left-menu">
    </div>
    <div class="right-bar">
        <div class="right-content">
            <div class="content">
                <div class="content-wrapper"> 
                    <div class="content-body">
                        Here is content
                    </div
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.left-menu {
    background-color: #0B0C0E;
    width: 20%;
    height: 100%;
    float: left;
}
.right-bar {
    background-color: #F0F0F0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
.right-content {
    float: left;
    width: 80%;
}
.right-content > .content {
    padding: 21px 0 0 42px;
}
.right-content > .content > .content-wrapper {
    width: 98%;
    height: 70%;
}
.right-content > .content .content-body {
    background-color: #FAFAFA;
    padding: 20px;
    font-size: 24px;
    border: 1px solid #D0D0D0;
}
```

sandbox for test: http://roonce.com/en/room/SwZuEJYB

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please include your HTML in the post; it's impossible for us to help you while 30 people are concurrently making changes to your sandbox content.

Comment: @TylerH, no problem. Attached to the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use "clear-fix" technique. http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/clear-fix/

This will allow the parent div to be the appropriate size of the floated elements within. Note this works specifically on #wrapper. (http://jsbin.com/huqehuta/1/edit)

```
.clear-fix:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
```